# Can I declare a variable using the value of an element's data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm building up an object where the key will be a string, and the value will be an array of values.

Here's what I'm looking at building...

```
myObject = { BAR = ['values', 'values'], BAR_2 = ['values', 'values'] }
```

So I'm getting stuck on making my 'BAR' arrays.  I want to use a data-attribute that is being passed into the function.

So let's assume this in the HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-foo="BAR">x</a>
```

I want to do this:

```
$(this).data('foo') = [];
```

so I have a new array called `BAR[]` which I can then push values into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the window object to reference the data-attributes that way, rather than eval. I think the way we handle our event binding was making the other solutions error out.

```
<a href="#" data-foo="BAR">x</a>

// set key to the  BAR[] array
   var key = window[ $this.data( 'foo' ) ];

// push value into BAR[]
   key.push( $this.data( 'values' ) );

// push the BAR['values'] array into the myObject object
   myObject[$this.data( 'foo' )] = key;
```

OUTPUT:

```
myObject = { BAR = ['values', 'values'], BAR_2 = ['values', 'values'] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this as a property of a larger object or array.

So if

```
var store = {};
```

then you can

```
store[$(this).data('foo')] = [];
```

if you want, you can also use the `this` object to store your var, though it doesn't make sense to do it like this in your case, because I'm guessing your code is inside some jquery event handler.

```
this[$(this).data('foo')] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use extend()? Seems to be exaclty what you need.

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-foo="BAR_1">x</a>
<a href="#" data-foo="BAR_2">x</a>
<a href="#" data-foo="BAR_3">x</a>
```

JS

```
var my_object = {};
var $link = $('a');

$.each($link, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var key = $this.data('foo');
    $.extend(my_object, my_object[key] = []);
});

console.log(my_object);
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/YK6bH/
(check the browser console.log)

docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your expected output and behavior is, so here's my stab. http://jsfiddle.net/y6a8H/

```
bar: <input type="text" data-foo="bar" /><br />
bar: <input type="text" data-foo="bar" /><br />
bar_2: <input type="text" data-foo="bar_2" /><br />
bar_2: <input type="text" data-foo="bar_2" /><br />
bar_2: <input type="text" data-foo="bar_2" /><br />
bar_3: <input type="text" data-foo="bar_3" />

$('[data-foo]').on('blur',function(){
    var vals = {};
    $('[data-foo]').each(function(i,e) {
        var data_foo = $(e).data('foo');
        vals[data_foo] = vals[data_foo] || [];
        vals[data_foo].push($(e).val());
    });
    console.log(vals);
})
```

When an input changes, I  build the object and log it. So this input will display

`{"bar":["a","b"],"bar_2":["c","d","e"],"bar_3":["f"]}`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the javascript function eval().  for example:

```
x = 'hello';
eval('var '+x+'="world"');
//the variable hello is now equal to the string "world"
```